# Is this true that $(\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C+2\cos A\cos B\cos C=1 \implies A+B+C=\pi)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Assume that  $A,B,C$ are positive real numbers and $A,B,C \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and we have
$$\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C+2\cos A\cos B\cos C = 1 $$
prove or disprove that $$A+B+C=\pi$$

Comment: $A,B,C$ must be restricted, otherwise the claim is not true.

Comment: I mean Is this true ? and if yes why?

Comment: Did you try to manipulate $cos(A+B+C)$ with the help of the addition-theorem $cos(x+y)=cos(x)cos(y)-sin(x)sin(y)$ ?

Comment: I didn't understand. @DietrichBurde

Comment: A solution is given [here](http://home.scarlet.be/math/Pgonio.htm).

Comment: I didn't get it. @DietrichBurde

Comment: Not true.  Check $A=B=C=\pi$ for e.g.  You need more restrictions. The reverse implication does hold true.

Comment: check this pdf document: [Link] (https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-content/uploads/mr_1_2015_solutions2.pdf) . page 25. solution for O327.

Comment: we can add this condition $A,B,C\in (0,\dfrac{\pi}{2})$,we can prove it

Comment: @math110: Indeed, the proof follows from the proof of the 8. example given [here](http://home.scarlet.be/math/Pgonio.htm), with the condition on $A,B,C$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $A=-\frac{\pi}2, B=C=\frac{\pi}4$ would be a counter e.g. to your proposal :(  The edited question looks good though.

Comment: I edited the question. please check it if it can be opened again.  @Dario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an obvious shorthand notation, we can solve the equation for $\cos C$:
$$c^2+2abc+a^2+b^2-1=0,$$

$$c=-ab\pm\sqrt{a^2b^2-a^2-b^2+1}=-ab\pm\sqrt{(1-a^2)(1-b^2)}.$$

Then
$$\cos C=-\cos A\cos B\pm \sin A\sin B=-\cos(A\pm B)$$
and
$$\pm C=\pi\pm A\pm B.$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $\pi-A-B$ for every occurrence of $C$.
$\cos{C}=
-{\cos{A}·\cos{B}}+{\sin{A}·\sin{B}}$
and
$\sin{C}=
{\sin{A}·\cos{B}}+{\cos{A}·\sin{B}}$
This will satisfy the stipulation that $A+B+C=\pi$.
By repeatedly grouping and substituting $1$ for every occurrence of $\cos^2{A}+\sin^2{A}$
or of
$\cos^2{B}+\sin^2{B}$,
you will eventually arrive at $1$.
PARDON THE CRAPPY FORMATTING! FOR THE LIFE OF ME, I CANNOT UNDERSTAND WHY MATHJAX BREAKS MY LINE WHEN THERE IS AMPLE SPACE ON THE SAME LINE FOR WHAT REMAINS. I'M FED UP.

Comment: Linebreak in the source = Linebreak in the final result. It's really that easy.